# HTTP-GET-to-HTTP-POST proxy

Tags: web-services, proxy, http-post

I'm writing a Yahoo Pipe that requires communication with a specific web service. Unfortunately, the web service only accepts POST, and the Yahoo Pipes Web Service JSON POST module issues the POST in the wrong format.

So ideally, there would be some proxy somewhere on the internet that accepts a GET, takes some parameters, and converts that to a POST, then returns the results. Any ideas if something like this exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this](http://code.google.com/p/convert-get-proxy/) code?

Comment: Looks interesting; however, I'd be looking for existing functional installations of this sort of project rather than source that I'd have to install on a server of my own.

Comment: @Reinderien--makes sense. I do believe the linked code can be installed on the AppEngine, but that's additional efforts you'd have to expand to get that going.